# asp.NET MVC losing referenced fields' values

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4, foreign-keys

I have a class

```
public partial class Advertisement
{
    public int AdvertisementId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public City CityIdFrom { get; set; }
    public City CityIdTo { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
}
```

which represents the table Advertisements. Same goes for a class City

```
public class City
{
    public Int32 CityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a view controller named View1Controller which has

```
DbConnection db = new DbConnection();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var query = from item in db.Advertisements.AsEnumerable() select item;

    return View(query);
}
```

And finally there is a View1.cshtml file

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.Advertisement>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View1";
}

<h2>View1</h2>

<table>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Description</td>
        <td>@item.CityIdFrom</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

I took a look in SQL Profiler and the query generated looked

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[AdvertisementId] AS [AdvertisementId], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[Weight] AS [Weight], 
[Extent1].[CityIdFrom_CityId] AS [CityIdFrom_CityId], 
[Extent1].[CityIdTo_CityId] AS [CityIdTo_CityId]
FROM [dbo].[Advertisements] AS [Extent1]
```

And executing the query I get:

```
2   None    5000    1   2
3   Test    1000    3   4
```

However, when query is hit, both CityIdFrom and CityIdTo are null for some reason. Thus the result table looks

```
None 
Test
```

Instead of expected

```
None 1
Test 3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you either need to add an Include for CityFrom and CityTo, or you Can make these referenced entities virtual. Option 1 (Include) avoids the select n+1 issue so commomn among ORMs.

```
var query = db.Advertisements.Include("CityIdFrom").Include("CityIdTo").AsEnumerable();
return View(query);
```

Comment: Virtual solved this :) And since I am really new to asp.NET, can you please explain Option 1 in more details? I did not understand about that inclusion :(

Comment: I appreciate your help so much :)) And thanks for updating :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using entity framework you'll need to make the properties virtual.

```
public partial class Advertisement
{
    public int AdvertisementId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual City CityIdFrom { get; set; }
    public virtual City CityIdTo { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the only caution against this is the select n+1 issue of not including the city entities.